# flip a file the way it is in shell

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file name file.txt as below.

```
xyz[4.3],default,
xyz[4.4],default, 
xyz[4.5],default, 
xyz[4.6],default,   
abc[1.1],rome, 
abc[1.2],rome,
ghi[1.1],moon, 
ghi[1.2],moon,
```

i want to flip the file like same format as it is in reverse manner.

```
ghi[1.2],moon, 
ghi[1.1],moon,
abc[1.2],rome,
abc[1.1],rome,
xyz[4.6],default, 
xyz[4.5],default,
xyz[4.4],default,
xyz[4.3],default,
```

tried this:

```
tr , '\n' <file.txt | sed '1!G; h; $!d' | tr '\n' , | sed 's/,$//'
```

but am getting file in a single line not as in a separate line as i mentioned above.

Comment: What's wrong with `sed '1!G;h;$!d'`?

Comment: [`tac file.txt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tac)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tac`

`tac` is the reverse of `cat`. Isn't it?